# Problem installing SQL Server on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, installation

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2016 on Windows 10. My problem is during installation, in the "Offline installation of Microsoft R Open and Microsoft R server" section, the next button is disabled and I can't proceed further installing the software. I appreciate if anyone could suggest a solution for this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2016 installation-offline installation of Microsoft R Open and Microsoft R server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47461985/11683)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server 2016 installation-offline installation of Microsoft R Open and Microsoft R server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461985/sql-server-2016-installation-offline-installation-of-microsoft-r-open-and-micros)

Comment: Thanks for all responses. The content of the links you provided mentioned my problem but right now I have a question whether for installing SQL server 2016 ,according to my issue, it is sufficient for solving the problem by just uncheck the "R server(standalone)" while a few other shared features such as "Data Quality Client" and "R services in-database" being checked?